# estimateGas for function calls

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Can someone suggest me how to use estimateGas for function calls like below:

await (MyContract.methods.addDoc(id,sha256hash).send({from: coinbase[0],gas: 1000000})

Comment: Replace `send` with `estimateGas` and get the return value (e.g., `var x = await...`). BTW, there's a redundant parenthesis at the beginning of the line (immediately after the `await`).

Comment: I know the function usage, the problem is what will be in the data field as addDoc function requires two parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let transaction = MyContract.methods.addDoc(id, sha256hash);
let block = await this.web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
let options = {
    to  : transaction._parent._address,
    data: transaction.encodeABI(),
    gas : block.gasLimit
};
let gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas(options);
console.log(gas);
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Can you tell me what is the significance of using getBlock("latest") here?

Comment: @AnubhavGupta: I'm not sure that you have to specify it in this case. I know that you need to specify it when you actually execute the transaction, so I kept it here for "best practice". You can try to see if it works without it.

Comment: And with regards to the significance for transaction execution: you need to specify your limit, in order to avoid the miner spending all your funds. If your limit is lower than the actual gas required, then the transaction will not go through. If your limit is higher than the actual gas required, then the transaction will go through, but **only** the actual gas required will be deducted from your account. So `gas: block.gasLimit` yields the highest chances of your transaction being executed.

Comment: The only problem is that you need to have the entire amount of funds in your account, EVEN THOUGH only the required amount of funds will be deducted from it. For example, suppose that: `gasPrice = 10`, `gasLimit = 20` and `gasRequired = 15`. So even though you'll end up spending 150 wei, the node first verifies that you have 200 wei in your account. Otherwise, it refrains from executing your transaction.

Comment: Thank you, do I need to add some extra gas for every transaction, just to be sure that transaction won't decline ?

Comment: @AnubhavGupta: I think that `estimateGas` may give an underestimate only if the function calls a function in another contract, but I'm not sure about that, to be honest. It's just something that I've encountered in my use-cases.